# Define type of class in dart

Tags: dart

Is it possible in this example to specify explicitly presize correct type for the "TypeA" variable (instead of `var` keyword`)?

```dart
class A{
  int i = 1;
  A(this.i);
}

A instance = A(1);

var TypeA = A;

A secondInstanceOfA = TypeA();
```

In the example above flutter engine auto detects `TypeA` as variable `Type` and I get the following error under compilation:

```
The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.
```

After all I also tried to change it to `(TypeA as A Function(int))(1)`. This workaround satisfies IDE analyzer, but in runtime - of course - leads to appropriate runtime error (`Expected a value of type '(int) => A', but got one of type '_Type'`)

Comment: If you do `typedef TypeA = A;` then it would work, because it really is the same type.
It would not be a `Type` object, but you should't be using `Type` objects for anything ... because, as you noticed, they're pretty useless. The only thing they're good for is doing `==` against other `Type` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` is precisely of type `Type`. You can use a constructor tear-off to achieve this:

```dart
class A {
  int i = 1;
  A(this.i);
}

A a1 = A(1)
const /* A Function(int) */ constructor = A.new;
A a2 = constructor(2);
```